# Branch and bound algorithm programming code

Tags: optimization, python, integer-programming, branch-and-bound, matlab

I want to solve an integer programming problem using the **branch and bound** method, but I'm having trouble finding the programming code. From what I saw, almost all algorithms use it for traveling salesman problems or job assignment cases. I need the branch and bound algorithm code to solve the problem of integer programming for **optimization** cases, with the aim of **maximization** or **minimization**. Does anyone have a source regarding branch and bound code for the optimization case? Or can anyone suggest where I can find the code? If anyone has it, please let me know. Any programming language doesn't matter as long as it can solve the problem of maximization or minimization in integer programming problems. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

There are several open-source software packages that use branch-and-bound to solve integer programming, for example:

- GLPK: https://www.gnu.org/software/glpk
- CBC: https://github.com/coin-or/Cbc

Answer (score 5):

Depending on the type of your MIP, there are numerous open-source options:

- MILP: [CBC](https://github.com/coin-or/Cbc)
- Convex MINLP: [Bonmin](https://github.com/coin-or/Bonmin)
- Non-convex MINLP: [Couenne](https://github.com/coin-or/Couenne)

All of the above: [SCIP](https://scip.zib.de/) (free for academics)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to work inside Excel (or LibreOffice), you might look at [OpenSolver](https://opensolver.org/). Google's [OR-Tools](https://developers.google.com/optimization) includes the CBC solver and the option to use GLPK, SCIP or Gurobi. (Gurobi is commercial software with a free academic license.)